# Karate Run option on individual scenario does not work for VSCode karate plugin

Tags: karate, vscode-extensions

I am facing a problem with the Karatelabs VSCode plugin i.e. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=karatelabs.karate.

My karate config file is calling a feature file which in turn is calling a JAVA file to get the user name of the machine to set some conditions.

The tests execute fine if I use the maven command or run from the runner file( .java). But when using Run option on an individual scenario, I get the following error

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: js failed:

01: Java.type('Package.JavaFile')

org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: Access to host class Package.JavaFile is not allowed or does not exist.
```

I have updated the classpath in the extension setting and tried including the .java files in POM but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension setting to change the run-mode to `maven`. It should then work. If not, please raise an issue with a way to replicate.

Refer image below:

[image]